# Adding css and excluding the checkout page

Tags: css, woocommerce, checkout

I want to add some css to all h3 except for the ones shown on the woocommerce checkout page, but still include h3s that I am displaying on the order-received page(which is an endpoint of the checkout page). If I use

```
   body:not(.page-id-xy) h3{
            ...;
   }
```

the h3s that I have on my order-received page aren't included either. Is there a selector specifically just for the checkout page w/o the order-received page?

Answer (score 1):

Depeding on your HTML structure, you can use the '>' selector to do what you desire. Be aware that '>' only selects the elements that are direct childs of defined parent element.
This is a little demo, showing how you can do it:

```css
:not(.container) > label{
     color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <label for="">123</label>
  </div>  


  <div class="container-1">
    <label for="">345</label>
  </div>
```

Don't forget, the h3 element must be a direct child of the page **.page-id-xy** element for this to work.

**UPDATE**

If it isn't a direct child, just use something like this:

```
:not(.container) > .inner-container label{
   color: red;
 }
```

Where **.inner-container** is the direct child.

Comment: i don't have a body class or something similar for the order-received page. It has the same classes as the checkout page , it is just an endpoint of that page. I need all h3s on my site to have this styling EXCEPT for the ones on the checkout page, but INCLUDING the ones on the checkout endpoint page "order-received".